# Update Panel to update only portion of repeater

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, repeater

I have an repeater in an update panel.  The repeater has a button and a grid. At runtime, there would be as many as 4 buttons to 4 grids. When button is clicked, data will be bound to the grid associated with it.  I want the partial postback on the grids so that if I click one button and data is bound to grid1, if I click another button to bind grid2, I don't want to lose the data already bound to grid1.

I understand controls inside update panel causes a partial page update.  But I get an error when I click on the dynamic buttons (similar to the error below).

I get an error if I try to register the button as ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl:

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'SessionSession342066'.
```

but I don't get an error if I register the button as ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl.  However, the latter will do a full postback of the entire repeater.

Because the id's are dynamic, I can't seem to add them to the `<Triggers>...`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you abandon the use of the updatepanel and use pure jQuery with web methods instead?  In that way, you could update any portion of the repeater at will without a postback.

Comment: Yes, I could, but I don't have the time to re-write everything.  The grid has a lot of logic built into - sorting, row highlighting due to difference scenarios.  If I use jquery, I'd have to clone the row and I found that cloning several hundred rows were taking too long in addition to add and removing css, not to mention the time it takes to test to make sure all of the functionality was still there.  Under time restraints, I thought the update panel would the least amount of work.